# Laravel - nested foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, nested

I am trying to move a webapp CRUD solution created outside a framework,
and now move it inside of Laravel. Below you see the section "standard PHP" which is a code that works, and the "Laravel that does not work.

**Question:** How do I write nested foreach loops in Laravel as identical as the one written in standard PHP example ?

**Laravel**

```
<table>

    <!-- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops -->

    @foreach ($response_body as $key => $value)
        @foreach ($value as $level2data => $array)

    <tr>
        <td>
           Hello
        </td>
    </tr>

        @endforeach
    @endforeach

</table>
```

Result of laravel code (printout on browser):

```
@foreach ($response_body as => $value) 
    @foreach ($value as $level2data => array) 

    @endforeach 
@endforeach
Hello
```

**Standard PHP**

```
<table>        

<?php foreach ($response_body as $key => $value):?>
        <?php foreach ($value as $level2data => $array):?>

    <tr>
        <td id="email">
            <?php echo "hello" . "\r\n"; ?>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Comment: You have some Obvious Woopsies in that code

Comment: 1. You start the `<table>` outside the loops, but close the table `</table>` inside the loop

Comment: This line: `@foreach ($resonse_body as => $value)` I suppose you mean `@foreach ($resonse_body as $value)`

Comment: So if you fix the little TYPO's you will at least be closer to a solution

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I updated the code, adjusting the typos.
I am bit confused why the "foreach" and "endforeach" are printed out to the browser.

Comment: "_I am bit confused why the "foreach" and "endforeach" are printed out to the browser_" That might be because your file is not named correctly and thus not parsed by Blade, make sure it has a `.blade.php` ending. Also: `<?php echo "Hello" . "\r\n"; ?>` Really no need to use `<?php ... ?>` here, just use `Hello` (you're in HTML/Blade)

Answer (score 0):

How about to build one array in your controller and not do a nested loop?

Instead of having 2 loops, pre-process your final array so you can clean up your code and maybe you can optimize your render time.

Comment: - Well, this is because I fetch data from an API source. When having the data locally I transform the data from json format to PHP array. The reason I use nested foreach-loop is that the array is a multidimensional array, thus the data I need is on level2/level3 in the array structure. I will go back and construct the API client data flow and see if I from there can follow your mentioned advice.

Comment: I will give it a try to construct the API client directly in the controller, to tap down the json data and transform it into an PHP array.